# Thm 5.27 in Suppes (Initialization+Recursion uniquely defines a function)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I am self-studying Suppes and am stuck at the proof of Theorem 5.27 for a while.
[image]

Notationally, $\omega$ denotes natural numbers. $n^\boldsymbol |$ denotes the successor of $n$.

I understand the main idea of this theorem: an initialization $H$ and a recursion formula $G$ uniquely define a function $F$. When going thru the proof, I am stuck at Eqn (1)--(4).

(2) says $f$ is a function on $\mathscr D(n)$, in other words, $f: \mathscr D(n)\rightarrow \mathscr R(G\cup H)\cup \{0\}$, which means the input of $f$ is an element of $\mathscr D(n)$, which itself should be a function $g: \{0,1\}\rightarrow \omega$. In the set-theoretical language, $g\in\omega^2$ and some elements of $g$ could be $\langle 0, 0\rangle, \langle 0, 1\rangle, \langle 0, 2\rangle, \cdots, \langle 1, 0\rangle, \langle 1, 1\rangle, \langle 1, 2\rangle, \cdots$. The first element could only be 0 or 1, and the second element could be some natural numbers.

(3), however, implies that $f$ could take $m,0$ as input, which rigorously by (4) I suppose should be $f(\langle m, 0\rangle)$. Here, $m$ could be every natural number, and thus $\langle m, 0\rangle$ is not necessarily in the domain of $f$.

I feel I have some confusion or error at a very detailed point. It would be much appreciated if anyone can point this out to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe I somehow figured out the confusion.

Here, $\langle m, n\rangle$ is not a pair $\{m, \{m,n\}\}$ as defined in Chapter 2. Rather $\langle m, n\rangle$ is a function $g:\{0,1\}\rightarrow \omega$, such that $g(0)=m$ and $g(1)=n$.

This is defined in Def 14 in the previous page:
[image]